# What is the execution order of the associative sub-query SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across this SQL at work, This was written by my colleague. Although there are better solutions, I’m just curious,and now I have simplified it as follows:

```
-- Calculate the total of the 'APPROVING' salary and the 'AGENT' salary already actual paid
SELECT  ifnull(sum(l.salary),0) + 
        (SELECT ifnull(sum(l1.salary),0) 
                FROM  salary_header h1 JOIN salary_lines l1 
                ON    h1.salary_id = l1.salary_id 
                WHERE h1.status='APPROVING' AND l1.project_id = l.project_id)
        FROM  salary_pay_headers h JOIN salary_pay_lines l 
        ON h.salary_pay_id = l.salary_pay_id 
        WHERE   h.pay_type='AGENT' 
        AND   l.project_id=9904
```

```
mysql> select * from salary_header;
+-----------+-----------+
| salary_id | status    |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | APPROVING |
|         2 | PAID      |
+-----------+-----------+
mysql> select * from salary_lines;
+----------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| salary_line_id | salary_id | project_id | salary |
+----------------+-----------+------------+--------+
|              1 |         2 |       9905 | 200.00 |
+----------------+-----------+------------+--------+
mysql> select * from salary_pay_headers;
+---------------+----------+
| salary_pay_id | pay_type |
+---------------+----------+
|             1 | AGENT    |
|             2 | OTHER    |
+---------------+----------+
mysql> select * from salary_pay_lines;
+--------------------+---------------+------------+--------+
| salary_pay_line_id | salary_pay_id | project_id | salary |
+--------------------+---------------+------------+--------+
|                  1 |             1 |       9904 |   3.05 |
|                  2 |             1 |       9904 | 201.37 |
|                  3 |             1 |       9904 |   6.10 |
|                  4 |             1 |       9904 |  10.17 |
|                  5 |             1 |       9904 |   6.44 |
|                  6 |             1 |       9904 |   9.15 |
|                  8 |             3 |       9905 | 100.00 |
+--------------------+---------------+------------+--------+
```

Its result is not 3.05+201.37+6.10+10.17+6.44+9.15=236.28 as I expected，but 236.28+200=436.28，obviously that one in the salary_line is not filtered out. I have spent the whole afternoon on this problem, so I really want to know the execution order of this SQL.

Comment: Could you be more clear about exactly are you trying to achieve? From your expected result, it seems that you trying to sum all the salaries of a particular project from salary_pay_lines. If thats the case, your query should be much simpler.

Comment: @RonCG,The question has been edited